Expo react native
Hi flocks i use create expo react native project about accessing mobile camera below i will provide my code. it will work fine till last week and i do change in my project like after login in my app camerascreen only apper on screen. but last few days after that change it throw only error i will provide my error IMG below.
Note: the errors are showing in about Camera and Flash in this two things only often to shows.
Help me to occur this error guy

HERE MY FULL CODE ABOUT CAMERASCREEN
/*Camera*/
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import {
  Button,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  Image,
  Modal,
} from 'react-native';
import { PanGestureHandler, State } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default function TakePhoto() {
  //const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [permission, requestPermission] = Camera.useCameraPermissions();
  const [photos, setPhotos] = useState([]);
  const [selectedPhoto, setSelectedPhoto] = useState(null);
  const [deleteConfirmationVisible, setDeleteConfirmationVisible] = useState(false);
  const [galleryOpen, setGalleryOpen] = useState(false);
  const totalPhotosCount = 5;
  const [remainingPhotos, setRemainingPhotos] = useState(totalPhotosCount);
  //const [flashMode, setFlashMode] = useState(Camera.Constants.FlashMode.off);
  const [flash, setFlash] = useState(Camera.Constants.FlashMode.off);
`your text`
  const panRef = useRef(null);
  const cameraRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!permission) {
      // Camera permissions are still loading
      return;
    }
    if (!permission.granted) {
      // Camera permissions are not granted yet
      requestPermission();
    }
  }, [permission, requestPermission]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setRemainingPhotos(totalPhotosCount - photos.filter(photo => !photo.deleted).length);
  }, [photos]);

  const takePicture = async () => {
    if (!cameraRef.current || !permission.granted || remainingPhotos === 0) {
      // Camera not ready or permission not granted
      return;
    }

    try {
      const photo = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync();
      setPhotos(prevPhotos => [...prevPhotos, { uri: photo.uri, deleted: false }]);
      setRemainingPhotos(prevCount => prevCount - 1); // Decrease remaining photos count
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to take picture:', error);
    }
  };

  const toggleFlashMode = () => {
    setFlash(
      flash === Camera.Constants.FlashMode.off
        ? Camera.Constants.FlashMode.on
        : Camera.Constants.FlashMode.off
    );
  };

  const toggleGallery = () => {
    setGalleryOpen(!galleryOpen);
    setSelectedPhoto(null); // Clear selected photo when opening/closing gallery
  };

  const deletePhoto = () => {
    if (!selectedPhoto) {
      return;
    }

    const updatedPhotos = photos.map(photo => {
      if (photo.uri === selectedPhoto.uri) {
        return { ...photo, deleted: true };
      }
      return photo;
    });

    setPhotos(updatedPhotos);
    setDeleteConfirmationVisible(false);
    setSelectedPhoto(null); // Clear selected photo after deletion

    if (updatedPhotos.every(photo => photo.deleted)) {
      setGalleryOpen(false); // Close the gallery menu if all photos are deleted
    }

    setRemainingPhotos(prevCount => Math.min(prevCount + 1, totalPhotosCount));
  };

  const onSwipeGestureEvent = (event) => {
    const { translationX } = event.nativeEvent;
    if (Math.abs(translationX) > 50) {
      const currentIndex = photos.findIndex(photo => photo === selectedPhoto);
      if (translationX > 0 && currentIndex > 0) {
        setSelectedPhoto(photos[currentIndex - 1]); // Swipe right
      } else if (translationX < 0 && currentIndex < photos.length - 1) {
        setSelectedPhoto(photos[currentIndex + 1]); // Swipe left
      }
      panRef.current.setOffset({ x: 0, y: 0 });
    }
  };

  const onSwipeHandlerStateChange = (event) => {
    if (event.nativeEvent.state === State.END) {
      panRef.current.setOffset({ x: 0, y: 0 });
    }
  };

  // const renderCamera = () => {
  //   if (!Permission === null) {
  //     // Camera permissions are still loading
  //     return <View style={styles.container}><Text>Loading...</Text></View>;
  //   }
  //   if (!hasPermission) {
  //     // Camera permissions are not granted
  //     return (
  //       <View style={styles.container}>
  //         <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>We need your permission to show the camera</Text>
  //         <Button onPress={requestPermission} title="Grant Permission" />
  //       </View>
  //     );
  //   }

  const renderCamera = () => {
    if (!permission || !permission.granted) {
      // Camera permissions not granted yet
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>We need your permission to show the camera</Text>
          <Button onPress={requestPermission} title="Grant Permission" />
        </View>
      );
    }

    const hasPhotos = photos.filter(photo => !photo.deleted).length > 0;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Camera 
          style={styles.camera}
          type={Camera.Constants.Type.back}
          flashMode={flash}
          ref={cameraRef}
        >
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.captureButton} onPress={takePicture}>
              <Text style={styles.captureText}> </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.galleryButton} onPress={toggleGallery}>
              {hasPhotos && (
                <Image source={{ uri: photos[photos.length - 1].uri }} style={styles.galleryThumbnail} />
              )}
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.flashButton} onPress={toggleFlashMode}>
              <Ionicons
                name={flash === Camera.Constants.FlashMode.off ? 'flash-off' : 'flash'}
                size={24}
                color="white"
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </Camera>
        <View style={styles.remainingPhotosText}>
          <Text style={styles.remainingPhotosText}>
            {totalPhotosCount - remainingPhotos}/{totalPhotosCount} Remaining Photos</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {renderCamera()}
      {photos.length > 0 && (
        <Modal visible={galleryOpen} transparent={true} animationType="fade">
          <View style={styles.galleryContainer}>
            {photos.map((photo, index) => (
              !photo.deleted && (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  key={index}
                  onPress={() => setSelectedPhoto(photo)}
                  style={styles.galleryPhotoContainer}
                >
                  <Image source={{ uri: photo.uri }} style={styles.galleryPhoto} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              )
            ))}
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.closeGalleryButton} onPress={() => setGalleryOpen(false)}>
              <Text style={styles.closeGalleryText}>Close Gallery</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </Modal>
      )}
      <Modal visible={!!selectedPhoto} transparent={true} animationType="fade">
        <PanGestureHandler
          onGestureEvent={onSwipeGestureEvent}
          onHandlerStateChange={onSwipeHandlerStateChange}
          ref={panRef}
        >
          <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
            <Image source={{ uri: selectedPhoto?.uri }} style={styles.fullscreenImage} />
            <View style={styles.menuContainer}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setSelectedPhoto(null)} style={styles.menuButton}>
                <Ionicons name="arrow-back-outline" size={24} color="white" style={styles.backIcon} />
                <Text style={styles.menuText}>Back</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.menuContainer1}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setDeleteConfirmationVisible(true)} style={styles.menuButton1}>
                <Ionicons name="trash-outline" size={24} color="red" style={styles.trashIcon} />
                <Text style={styles.menuText1}>Delete</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        </PanGestureHandler>
      </Modal>
      <Modal visible={deleteConfirmationVisible} transparent={true} animationType="fade">
        <View style={styles.deleteConfirmationContainer}>
          <View style={styles.deleteConfirmationBox}>
            <Text style={styles.deleteConfirmationText}>Delete 1 item?</Text>
            <View style={styles.deleteConfirmationButtons}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.CancelButton}
                title="Cancel"
                onPress={() => setDeleteConfirmationVisible(false)}
              >
                <Text style={styles.TextCancel}>Cancel</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <View style={{ width: 20 }} />
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.deleteButton}
                title="No"
                onPress={deletePhoto}
              >
                <Text style={styles.TextDelete}>Delete</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 ....
});

